# No me carga el background image desde el archivo css

Tags: html, css

No se que ocurre si estoy linkeando de manera correcta la imagen al body con la propiedad background-image. En cambio cuando la utilizo con style desde el html en el body si la carga normal. Este es el html:

```
<html>
     <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilodrum.css">
<title>Drumbox</title>
  </head>
     <body>


        </body>
       </html>
```

Y este es el CSS:

```
body{
background-image: url('img/concierto.png');
```

}

Cuando ingreso a la consola me muestra este error:
**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**

Que podria ser?

Comment: el error es porque el archivo de imagen no se encuentra en esa dirección ingresa ala url de la imagen en tu navegador vea si se encuentra ahí si no es así intenta usando otra ubicación saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hola intenta cualquiera de las dos opciones, si tu hoja de estilo esta solo dentro de una carpeta utiliza la primera opcion, si son 2 la segunda y asi..

```
    body{
background-image: url('./img/concierto.png');
}

    body{
background-image: url('../img/concierto.png');
}
```